# How to hide s3 bucket and access key credentials from an Html file

Tags: java, html, security

I have an HTML web app running that uploads files into an s3 bucket.

There is logic written in javascript embedded into this html file. Within this script there are access keys passwords and the name of the bucket. 
Anyone visiting the site can see this via a right click and inspecting the source.

Is there a way to mask this very sensitive information?

**********additional information
This is what you see via "inspect source"

```
<script>
        bsCustomFileInput.init();
        AWS.config.httpOptions.timeout = 0;
        const s3 = new AWS.S3({
            accessKeyId: 'asdfasdf23423sdfadf',
            secretAccessKey: 'asdfasdf2342412341234234',
            region: 'us-east-2'
        });


          var params = {
                Bucket: 'Bucketname',
```

Comment: No, there's not. You'll have to do the signing operations on the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to this which involves using AWS lambda and AWS API gateway to generate a "presigned url".

The steps involved are detailed in this great [tutorial](https://github.com/miztiik/AWS-Demos/tree/master/How-To/setup-pre-signed-s3-urls).

Answer (score 0):

Can you post an example with dummy values of access keys only? As of the moment I cannot imagine if you have a post processing function or it is just a direct request after a click of an html element.

Comment: please see amended question abovee

Answer (score 0):

use temperary credentials and Policy to hide your bucket

Comment: how do you go about doing this?